# What is the best way to throw errors in Outlook

Tags: api, user-interface, office-js

I am making an Outlook taskpane add-in and want to show an Error Massage if my backend is not reachable. But I do not know how to open an Error box or the yellow error massage that Outlook uses is there a way?

[image: The Error box I would like to use.]

or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The yellow box is currently an internal feature, and we don't have JS APIs available to show that. You can request this as a new feature and we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Otherwise, you could just create your own error message box in the taskpane to show the users.